# Isometry group of a compact Pseudo-Riemannian manifold

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, principal-bundles

Can someone give an example of a compact Pseudo-Riemannian manifold (that is a manifold with an indefinite metric) with non-compact isometry group?

Here is some more background to my question:

Myers and Steenrod proved that the isometry group of a Riemannian manifold is a lie group and furthermore if the manifold is compact so is the isometry group. 
One can also prove that the isometry group of a Pseudo-Riemannian manifold is a lie group too. But in this case the isometry group is not compact in general even if the manifold is.

Comment: Hint: 2-dimensional torus with a suitable flat Lorentzian metric will be an example.

Comment: @MoisheCohen could you elaborate? I'm unable to make it an example (and according to Corollary D in https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02575, it cannot be an example if the isometry group is assumed to be transitive).

Comment: @YCor take any Anosov element A of SL(2,Z). It preserves some flat Lorentzian structure invariant under the full group of translations. Now take the quotient of the plane by the integer group $Z^2$. The mapping A projects to an isometry (generating a noncompact group) of the quotient flat Lorentzian torus. I hope it is clear now. Of course, this cyclic groups of isometries is not transitive.

Comment: @YCor: The full isometry group is indeed bigger than cyclic (it does contain all translations as well as some symmetries) but it is noncompact. The key is the action of the projection of A on the 1st homology: The order is infinite. Thus, the full isometry group has to have infinitely many components. See my answer for details.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks, you're right, I was not careful. There's no contradiction with the paper I mentioned above because the *connected component* of the isometry group is indeed compact.

Comment: can anyone provide a reference for the statement that "the isometry group of a Pseudo-Riemannian manifold is a lie group too. But in this case, the isometry group is not compact in general even if the manifold is."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the details for my comment above.

A matrix $A\in SL(2,{\mathbb Z})$ is called **Anosov** if its eigenvalues have absolute value different from $1$. Equivalently, $tr(A)\notin [-2,2]$. 
Given any two distinct 1-dimensional subspaces $L_1, L_2\subset {\mathbb R}^2$ there is a unique, up to scale, nondegenerate bilinear form $b$ on ${\mathbb R}^2$ which vanishes on both lines. (If $e_i$ is a generating vector of $L_i$ then the form $b$ is uniquely determined by $b(e_1,e_2)$. For instance, if $L_1, L_2$ are the coordinate axes then $b(x,y)=xy$.) 
This form defines a Lorenztian metric on ${\mathbb R}^2$. If $A\in SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ preserves both lines $L_1, L_2$ then it preserves the form $b$ as well. Now, given an Anosov matrix $A\in SL(2, {\mathbb Z})$ let $L_1, L_2$ be its eigenspaces (both eigenvalues have to be real and distinct) and $b$ be the corresponding bilinear form which has to be invariant under $A$. The linear transformation $A$ preserves the standard integer lattice ${\mathbb Z}^2$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$ and, hence, descends to an automorohism $f: T^2= {\mathbb R}^2/{\mathbb Z}^2$. The bilinear form descends to a flat Lorenzian metric $g$ on $T^2$ invariant under the automorphism $f$. Thus, $Isom(T^2, g)$ contains the infinite cyclic group $\Gamma$ generated by $f$. I claim that $\Gamma$ is not contained in any Lie group $G$ with finitely many component acting (topologically) on $T^2$. Indeed, $f$ induces an infinite order automorphism on the 1st homology group $H_1(T^2, {\mathbb Z})$, namely the one given by the matrix $A$, where we use projections of the standard coordinate vectors in ${\mathbb R}^2$ as the generators of the homology group. If $G$ is a subgroup of $Homeo(T^2)$ containing $\Gamma$ then the path connected component of identity $G^0$ of $G$ acts trivially on the 1-st homology group $H_1(T^2, {\mathbb Z})$. Hence, if $G$ has only finitely many connected components then the image of $G$ in $Aut(H_1(T^2, {\mathbb Z}))$ 
is finite. Thus, the automorphism $f$ as above cannot belong to such $G$. Since every compact group has only finitely many connected components, it follows that $f$ cannot belong to any compact Lie subgroup of $Homeo(T^2)$. Since the isometry group of any pseudo-Riemannian manifold is a Lie group, it follows that $Isom(T^2, g)$ is noncompact. qed

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group (e.g., $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$), $\Gamma$ a cocompact lattice. The Killing form yields a bi-invariant pseudo-Riemannian structure on $G$, which thus passes to the compact manifold $G/\Gamma$. The isometry group of the latter contains $G$ and therefore cannot be compact (unless $G$ is compact, which is precisely when the metric is positive-definite up to sign).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is a bit more advanced than I hoped but I get the idea. What would be a concrete example of $G$ and $\Gamma$? I'm not familiar with the concept of cocompact lattice that's why I ask.

Comment: Let $S$ be a closed surface, with a Riemannian metric of curvature $-1$ and fundamental group $\Gamma$. Then $\Gamma$ naturally acts by orientation-preserving isometries on the universal covering of $S$, which is the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$, whose oriented isometry group is isomorphic to $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$. Then the image of $\Gamma$ in $G$ is a cocompact lattice.

Comment: I tried to elaborate it and now I have two more questions 1. $G$ is not compact, so why is $G/\Gamma$ compact? 2. Why does the isometry group of the Pseudo-Riemannian metric on $G/\Gamma$ contain $G$? More detailed: In the example with the hyperbolic plane $G$ is the isometry group of $\mathbb{H}^2$ (w.r. to a Riemannian metric). So why is $G$ contained in the isometry group of the Pseudo-Riemannian metric on $G/\Gamma$?

Comment: We can write the hyperbolic plane as $K\backslash G$ (left quotient, $K$ is compact) and the compact surface is the double quotient $K\backslash G/\Gamma$, and it is easy to deduce that $G/\Gamma$ is compact.

Comment: To show that the left $G$-action on $G/\Gamma$ is by pseudo-isometries, use that the pseudo-metric on $G$ is bi-invariant (right-invariance allows to pass it to the quotient and left-invariance implies the left $G$-action is isometric).

Comment: The surface hyperbolic plane was just a recipe to produce a cocompact lattice. Once you have a cocompact lattice, you can forget how you produced it. That $G$ acts by pseudo-Riemannian isometries on $G/\Gamma$ holds for every discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ of $G$.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: It might be interesting to OP that the pseudo Riemannian manifold described in the comments here is the unit tangent bundle of a hyperbolic surface of genus $ g\geq 2$. In other words the same way that SL_2(R) is a circle bundle over the (noncompact) hyperbolic plane then $ SL_2(R)/\Gamma $ is a circle bundle over a (compact) surface of genus $ g\geq 2 $. Here as Ycor previously stated $\Gamma_g $ is the fundamental group of a surface of genus $ g $ and hyperbolic just means constant curvature $ -1 $.